# The relationship between the operator and its adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, adjoint-operators

Let $V$ be a Hilbert space, $T: V \rightarrow V$  be a bounded linear operator, $T^*$ be the adjoint operator of $T$. Suppose that $T$ and $T^*$ have the same kernel, and the range of $T$ is $V_1$, where $V_1$ is a closed subspace of $V$. How to prove that the range of $T^*$ is $V_1$?

Comment: This follows from the closed range theorem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$ker(T)^{\bot} = \overline{im(T^*)}$ if $T$ is a linear operator between Hilbert spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3766750/kert-bot-overlineimt-if-t-is-a-linear-operator-between-hilbert) Oh no sorry, it does not prove that the range of your $T^*$ is closed.

Comment: This one seems more appropriate: [Is it true that $\text {ran} (T^*)$ is closed whenever $\text {ran} (T)$ is closed?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054117).